# LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer exception on Play 1.2.5.4 - How can I debug this (or workaround it)?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a controller that receives requests to generate CSVs asynchronously with continuations that is giving me an Exception:

```
Oops: UnexpectedException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception UnexpectedException: 
While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer on
 controllers.Productions
```

I have managed to narrow down the problem to the await line. If I remove it, I don't get the exception. Can anyone help me how to debug the problem further or suggest a workaround?

Productions controller:

```
@Check("user")
public static void exportz(int iDisplayStart, int sEcho, String sSearch,
 String searchFields) {
    ObjectType ztype = ObjectType.get(getControllerClass());


    Triple<String,String,String> triplet = parseListJSON(iDisplayStart, sEcho, sSearch, searchFields);
    String where = triplet.getLeft();
    String orderField = triplet.getMiddle();
    String orderDir = triplet.getRight();

    ExportCSV csvGen = new ExportCSV( ztype,  where, orderField,orderDir,sSearch,searchFields);
    response.contentType = "text/csv";
    do {
        Promise<String> csvGeneration =csvGen.now();
        String someCsvData =  await(csvGeneration);
        response.writeChunk(someCsvData);
    }while(csvGen.moreData());
}
```

Exception:

```
Oops: UnexpectedException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception UnexpectedException: While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer on controllers.Productions
play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying play.CorePlugin@7e6b9547 on controllers.Productions
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:556)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses$ApplicationClass.enhance(ApplicationClasses.java:235)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadApplicationClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:167)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:431)
    at play.Play.preCompile(Play.java:593)
    at play.Play.init(Play.java:299)
    at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:159)
Caused by: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer on controllers.Productions
    at play.CorePlugin.enhance(CorePlugin.java:302)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:551)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: by javassist.bytecode.BadBytecode: invalid opcode address
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:777)
    at play.classloading.enhancers.LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer.enhanceThisClass(LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer.java:269)
    at play.CorePlugin.enhance(CorePlugin.java:297)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: javassist.bytecode.BadBytecode: invalid opcode address
    at javassist.bytecode.CodeIterator.nextOpcode(CodeIterator.java:586)
    at javassist.bytecode.CodeIterator.next(CodeIterator.java:157)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Liveness.analyze(Liveness.java:237)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Liveness.computeUsage(Liveness.java:216)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Liveness.compute(Liveness.java:38)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypedBlock.makeBlocks(TypedBlock.java:54)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:91)
    at javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo.rebuildStackMap(MethodInfo.java:404)
    at javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo.rebuildStackMapIf6(MethodInfo.java:389)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:768)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, I solved the problem changing the method to a new controller. I think LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer has one of the oldest bugs on PlayFramework that probably will never be solved.

Comment: I ended up solving this issue by moving the code I wanted to add into a private method and calling that instead. But even that doesn't work 100% of the time. My actual advice would be to run away from Play 1.x as quickly as possible.